# grails schema-export columns nullable, how to set always

Tags: grails, database-schema

Friends:
When I do grails schema-export on an app, the columns are all automatically marked as being **not null**.

This is a real pain in the neck and I have to set the class attributes as **nullable** in the constraints  section to prevent the DDL statement having a not nullable.

Any way to say “all columns are nullable unless I say other wise”. ?

Thanks for your time and attention.

-N

Answer (score 0):

```
grails.gorm.default.constraints = {
    '*'(nullable: true)
}
```

See the docs on global constraints: https://docs.grails.org/latest/ref/Constraints/Usage.html